# php summing up a particular value inside array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
foreach ($retrievependingorders as $pendingorders){
        $orderno = $pendingorders['order_no'];
        $lastupdate = $pendingorders['order_update_date'];
        $orderstatus = $pendingorders['order_status'];
        $totalprice = $pendingorders['total_price'];

        echo "<tr><td>$orderno</td><td>$lastupdate</td><td>$orderstatus</td><td><center>$totalprice</center></td></tr>";
}
```

Guys, I have a foreach loop echo-ing all the database rows into tables. May I know how to sum up all the 'totalprice' exist in the pendingorders array?

Comment: So to clarify $grand_total_price += $totalprice is short for $grand_total_price = $grand_total_price + $totalprice

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($retrievependingorders as $pendingorders){
        $orderno       = $pendingorders['order_no'];
        $lastupdate    = $pendingorders['order_update_date'];
        $orderstatus   = $pendingorders['order_status'];
        $totalprice    = $pendingorders['total_price'];
        $total        += $totalprice;

        echo "<tr><td>$orderno</td><td>$lastupdate</td><td>$orderstatus</td><td><center>$totalprice</center></td></tr>";
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do, take a var outside loop and add all the  `$totalprice` to it !!

```
$grand_total = 0 ;

foreach ($retrievependingorders as $pendingorders){
        $orderno = $pendingorders['order_no'];
        $lastupdate = $pendingorders['order_update_date'];
        $orderstatus = $pendingorders['order_status'];
        $totalprice = $pendingorders['total_price'];
        $grand_total += $totalprice ; // Here we are summing the values
        echo "<tr><td>$orderno</td><td>$lastupdate</td><td>$orderstatus</td><td><center>$totalprice</center></td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right

```
foreach ($retrievependingorders as $pendingorders){
        $orderno = $pendingorders['order_no'];
        $lastupdate = $pendingorders['order_update_date'];
        $orderstatus = $pendingorders['order_status'];
        $totalprice = $pendingorders['total_price'];
        $sum_totalprice +=$totalprice

        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"/enter-online-icas/my-orders/order-details/?orderno=".$orderno."\">$orderno</a></td><td>$lastupdate</td><td>$orderstatus</td><td><center>$totalprice</center></td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>".$sum_totalprice."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a variable to hold a running count.

`PHP`

```
$grand_total_price = 0; //Initialize your variables

foreach ($retrievependingorders as $pendingorders){
    $orderno = $pendingorders['order_no'];
    $lastupdate = $pendingorders['order_update_date'];
    $orderstatus = $pendingorders['order_status'];
    $totalprice = $pendingorders['total_price'];
    $grand_total_price += $totalprice;

    echo "<tr><td>$orderno</td><td>$lastupdate</td><td>$orderstatus</td><td><center>$totalprice</center></td></tr>";
```

}

echo "My Grand Total: " . $grand_total_price . "";